# Unable to download the pecl install gearman on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, gearman

I'm trying to setup gearman on Ubuntu, installations is failed and showing the below error.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gearman.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/gearman.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/gearman.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/gearman.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/gearman.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
pecl/gearman requires PHP (version >= 5.1.0, version <= 6.0.0, excluded versions: 6.0.0), installed version is 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Comment: Provide more details, please. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26632626).

Answer (score 0):

The message details the locations it's looking for the gearman.so file - put it in one of those locations and it should work.

However the latest version from http://pecl.php.net/package/gearman is already packaged for Ubuntu so I would prefer to install it with apt.  This is what I get on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ sudo apt install php-gearman
$ echo '<?php print gearman_version() . "\n"; ?>' > gearman_test.php
$ php gearman_test.php
1.1.18+ds
```